# How to allow cross-domain requests with local-web-server?

Tags: http-status-code-504, local-web-server

I use [local-web-server](https://www.npmjs.com/package/local-web-server) 5.3.0 to run my single page application locally:

```bash
ws --spa index.html
```

When the app tries to get data from a publically available URL `https://www.my-domain.com/my-file.json`, the request fails with:

```
Status 504 Gateway Timeout
Referrer Policystrict-origin-when-cross-origin
```

I have tried the following commands but had no success:

```bash
ws --cors.origin my-domain.com --spa index.html
ws --cors.origin www.my-domain.com --spa index.html
ws --cors.origin https://www.my-domain.com --spa index.html
ws --cors.credentials --cors.origin my-domain.com --spa index.html
ws --cors.credentials --cors.origin www.my-domain.com --spa index.html
ws --cors.credentials --cors.origin https://www.my-domain.com --spa index.html
```

How can I fix this?